# How to give edit permission only to specific fields in node edit in?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

I have content type with some cck fields:

```
- task time
- task status
- task executor
- task category
```

and of course title/body and other drupal node default fields.

each node of this content type will be assigned to a user selected from site users in task executor field.

I want the when the executor logins view all fields of assigned to task(node) but only can change (edit) the value of task status field. node edit doesn't do that.

I try to use 'Content Permissions' of cck module but it is not what I really need. it doesn't have control on title and body field and also the user can only see the fields he has edit permission on them in node edit page.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only want them to be able to edit the status field and nothing else I would not give them access to the node edit page. The [editablefields](https://drupal.org/project/editablefields) module allows you to allow the user to change a field on the nodes page using AJAX. You may still need another module to get the permissions all worked out.

Or you could create a custom module/block which lets the user change the status and make the block only show up on node pages of that content type.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Field Permissions](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module to allow specific users view or edit fields. Of course you must have a relation field (Task Executor field) for the Executor for each node so that these permissions can apply.

Answer (score 0):

There are few fine grain permissions module like field permissions. Please use any of them.